# finding the maxima and minima for $f(x) = \sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis

the actual question is to show that the function$f(x) = \sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$ for all x belongs to $R$ has a minimum at $x=\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$ and maxima at $x=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and at $x=\left(\frac{-\pi}{6}\right)$.

Actually the $f'(x)$ is coming to be $\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right) + \cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=  \sin(2x)$ $\Rightarrow$x=$\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I am not getting how to find the other 2 points $x=\frac{-\pi}{6}$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$.

there is only- **ONE** critical point which is $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: You are apparently restricting the possible values $\;x\;$ can attain, as $$\;\sin 2x=0\iff x=\frac\pi2+\frac n2\pi\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb Z\;$$ As for the other points you mention: perhaps the function's domain is a bounded closed interval?

Comment: $\pm\pi/6$ *definitely* aren't critical points but can be minimum/maximum in some closed interval as @Joanpemo already said.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding first the original formula you can see better what is happening:
$$
f(x) = \sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right) =
\frac14-\cos^2 x.
$$